# Fill NA Values in R with Data from Other Data Frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 2 data frames with some identical and unique columns. The first data frame has some NA values in the identical columns. I would like to replace those with the data from the second data frame and join all columns into 1 data frame. Ultimately, the solution will need to be done with very large data frames so efficiency is ideal.

Intial data frames:

```
df1 = data.frame(x = c("Canada", "Canada", NA, NA), 
            y = c(2010, 2010, 2011, 2011), 
            z = c(NA, NA, "CAN", "CAN"),
            Code = c(2, 6, 2, 6))

df2 = data.frame(x = c("Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada"), 
             y = c(2013, 2012, 2011, 2010), 
             z = c("CAN", "CAN", "CAN", "CAN"), 
             GDP = c(22, 20, 18, 16))
```

Expected result:

```
df3 = data.frame(x = c("Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada"), 
             y = c(2010, 2010, 2011, 2011), 
             z = c("CAN", "CAN", "CAN", "CAN"),
             Code = c(2, 6, 2, 6), 
             GDP = c(16, 16, 18, 18))
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly. Don't post code, data, or error messages as pictures, post the text directly here on SO.

Comment: Please do not post images of data: they cannot copy/pasted by us, they mask the true nature of the data, screen readers do nothing with them, and some mobile devices have a hard time with larger images. To make this question reproducible, can you replace the images with the output of `dput(x)` where `x` is a representative sample of the data? This might be something like `dput(head(GDP[1:5]))` if those are enough rows/columns to adequately represent the data. (Same for the other frame(s).)

Comment: Easiest would be to use `left_join()` from `dplyr`, making a new variable rather than trying to fill the `NA`s. The code would be something like `newdf <- dfA %>% left_join(dfB, by  = "Country")`.

Comment: I think I've formatted the post appropriately. I'm unsure how to create the nice tables I see in other posts but the output of the code above demonstrates the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a more concise way to write this, but it should execute pretty quickly, since it relies primarily on two joins.

First, I make a lookup table from `df2`, which I assume has a single value of `z` for each value of `x`. The lookup table only needs those two columns.

```
library(dplyr)
lookup <- df2 %>% distinct(x, z)
```

Then I do two joins, first joining `df1` with `lookup` using `z` to get a consistent `x`, and then using the clean set of `x`, `y,` and `Code` to join with `df2` to get the corresponding `z` and `GDP` values.

```
df1 %>%
  left_join(lookup, by = "z") %>%
  mutate(x = if_else(is.na(x.x), x.y, x.x)) %>%
  select(x, y, Code) %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("x", "y")) %>%
  select(x, y, z, Code, GDP)  # Optional, just to resort columns

#       x    y   z Code GDP
#1 Canada 2010 CAN    2  16
#2 Canada 2010 CAN    6  16
#3 Canada 2011 CAN    2  18
#4 Canada 2011 CAN    6  18
```

Comment: Thank you so much! For some reason, it created 4 duplicates of all the observations it filled in z for but those can easily be dropped and is most likely something I've done wrong. This was exactly what I needed though.